# Can I send Hero cards to whats app by using Twilio

Tags: node.js, twilio, botframework, chatbot

I have chat bot, I build it with bot framework nodejs SDK I integrate this chat bot to whatsapp and I want to display some buttons in the whatsapp chat,

So is there any one found a solution for this problem pleas help me

> Note: I try to send a hero card but I run to problem

```
Error: TwilioWhatsAppAdapter.parseActivity():
 An activity text or attachment with contentUrl must be specified.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how bot framework attempts to send WhatsApp messages with buttons, but I doubt it fits with the way Twilio wants to send them.

Currently, to send a message with buttons, you need to [register and use a template message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates). When you send the text of a message that matches one of your templates, then Twilio will deliver the entire template with buttons as well.

For the future, look out for the [Twilio Content API](https://www.twilio.com/go/messaging-content-api-request-access-1) which will streamline templates, buttons and other rich messages across platforms.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the [TwilioWhatsAppAdapter](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-js/tree/master/libraries/botbuilder-adapter-twilio-whatsapp) from the botbuilder-community-js repo.

Looking at the adapter's code, it doesn't appear to be configured to handle any card other than a 'signin' card (see [here](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-adapter-twilio-whatsapp/src/twilioWhatsAppAdapter.ts#L392)). If you don't mind doing a little leg work on this, I don't see why you couldn't fork this repo and build in functionality that supports a hero card similar to the signin implementation.

I imagine it would look something like this:

```js
case 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero':
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-case-declarations
  const hero = attachment.content;

  message.body = `${ hero.text }\n\n`;
  message.body += (hero.buttons[0].title ? `*${ hero.buttons[0].title }*\n` : '');
  message.body += hero.buttons[0].value;
  break;
```

The above may need a little massaging but it wouldn't be far off from this. Then, you just need to build the library for use.